# Angular 2 dynamic reference

Tags: forms, angular, input, dynamic, reference

I want to generate inputs for form dynamically and I want to know if I can create references dynamically. I want to use references for validate form inputs.

I want to know if I can do something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let input in inputs">
     <input type="text" [attr.name]="input.name" class="form-control" required 
       [(ngModel)]="model[input.name]" #input.name="ngModel"
       [ngClass]="{'error_input': (input.name.valid || !input.name.pristine)     
        || form.submitted, 'valid_input': input.name.valid}">
</div>
```

If you know other method to validate form please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: check this link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html to create the inputs dynamically and apply validation

Comment: @rashfmnb my problem is with validation not with create inputs dynamically, if you can, give me some suggestion about apply validation. Thanks

Comment: check this plnkr https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview go to question.service.ts and add required and then check how it is working

Comment: this plnkr is empty

Comment: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/cb-dynamic-form/ts/eplnkr.html sorry for empty one